# Sort list of objects using Collection.sort() with lambdas only

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, comparable

I am beginner in **lambdas** and trying to understand how it works. So I have this list of **Student** with id and score attributes and I have to sort it accoding to the score . My Code

```
import java.util.*;

class Student {

    int id, score;

    public Student(int id, int score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.score = score;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.id + " " + this.score;
    }
}

interface StudentFactory < S extends Student > {
    S create(int id, int score);
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] ad) {

        StudentFactory < Student > studentFactory = Student::new;
        Student person1 = studentFactory.create(1, 45);
        Student person2 = studentFactory.create(2, 5);
        Student person3 = studentFactory.create(3, 23);

        List < Student > personList = Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person3);

         // error in the below line
        Collections.sort(personList, (a, b) -> (a.score).compareTo(b.score));
        System.out.println(personList);
    }
}
```

as you can see I tried `Collections.sort(personList, (a, b) -> (a.score).compareTo(b.score));` it gave me error `int cannot be dereferenced` I know the error expected I just want to show what I wanted.
**So is there any way to sort the Student object accoding to score using lambdas only?**
I have also seen similar post where I found that `List.sort` or `BeanComparator` is the other option but is there any way I can do it with lambdas?
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.score, b.score)
```

would work.  `int` is not an object, it is a primitive, and you can't call `int.compareTo`, or any other methods on `int`.

Even better than that would be

```
Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.score)
```

or, with a getter,

```
Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getScore)
```

And using `List.sort` doesn't make a difference as to whether or not you use lambdas or whatever.  You just write `personList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.score))` instead of `Collections.sort(personList, Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.score))`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but how can I change order to `desc` in `compareInt` case?

Comment: By calling `.reversed()` on the Comparator.

Comment: it gave error on `Collections.sort(personList,Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.score).reversed());` saying cannot find the symbol `s.score`

Comment: You may need to write `(Student s) -> s.score` instead then.